# Call Instructions Anchor IDL error address not inicialized

Tags: anchor, instructions, idl

I am trying to replicate some calls to an Anchor IDL of a contract. And all the instructions work for me, but the most important one doesn't. And I have a couple of doubts, comparing my calls with the originals:

original: https://solscan.io/tx/2XtSt89dj1xvxqPPS6pZSunMmzW6wwaEXi5NH7UH5pbLxrSoE9SGtjCJxTtfoA25GDcb8BwCQY5FA31LEBB8LFQz

own: https://solscan.io/tx/5M8JiBq5zBk6Vb2LT51T2JVdhnEwuDKoRJCdu1YLexcyPcRkquWFcUsyyLKMfbW1AwENK1syW37E2z2X1Fjoxjq

I see that I am not performing the 'Compute Budget' although this call does work, the next one no longer works, it gives me an error that one of the addresses is not initialized. Although I have confirmed that I send the same addresses as the original call: https://solscan.io/tx/48Uft8kRb9ogCju13hV7Ae8v12HJiZQ6JvbuJCfSTxZzYpMfv67cDqDbjTruZfyTijU23ALkTMFTJChxBSAhnE4a

Can someone guide me a little? I'm doing it with npm TypeScrypt

Thank you!

Comment: Sorry, there might be something unclear here, but both `original` and `own` are successful transactions, and use identical accounts + instruction data. Can you add the failing transaction?